# Creating a column variable taking the mean of a variable conditional on two other variables

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pivot

I have a data frame that shows the mean `'dwdime'` for each of the given conditions:

```
DIMExCand_means = DIMExCand.groupby(['cycle', 'coded_state', 'party.orig', 'comtype']).mean()
```

[image]

I have created a pivot table from DIMExCand_means with the following command and output:

```
DIMExCand_master = pd.pivot_table(DIMExCand_means,index=["Cycle","State"])
```

[image]

However, some data gets lost in the process. I would like to add columns to the `'DIMExCand_master'` dataframe that includes the mean `'dwdime'` score given each possible combination of `'party.orig'` and `'comptype'`, as this will allow me to have one entry per `'cycle'-'coded_state'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try:

```
DIMExCand_means = DIMExCand_means.reset_index()
DIMExCand_master = DIMExCand_master.reset_index()

pd.merge(DIMExCand_means, DIMExCand_master, left_on=['cycle','coded_state'], right_on=['Cycle','State'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks!

I ended up going with:

DIMExCand_dime = pd.pivot_table(DIMExCand, values = 'dwdime', index ["Cycle","State"], columns='ID', aggfunc=np.mean)